# How to validate authenticity of app downloaded from App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, security, mac-appstore

How can I be sure that an app I download from the App Store is indeed from the vendor it is supposed to be?

Anyone with a developer account can potentially pretend to be for example "a bank" and sell a fake app through the App Store.

The only way I can think of is that you go to the website of your bank, verify the SSL certificate and from there follow a direct HTTP link to the App Store.

Any other way of making sure the app is authentic?

Comment: What meets your definition for Authentic? The simple answer is turn on Gatekeeper to only run App Store apps and by clicking on the app, you are more or less guaranteed it's as Apple approved it.

Comment: Authentic in a sense of "really from this specific vendor". For example take the bank "ING-DiBa", they have one official app in the store (German store) but if you search for "ing" you'll find many others that seem to be banking apps but I just don't know whether they are. I'm not sure if this falls under the Apple approval process.

Comment: Thanks. Apple vets the companies that are allowed on the store quite rigorously - tax records, articled of incorporation, etc. are checked so the risk seems to be all on the network and whether you feel some state or network actor has gone to the trouble to spoof certificates or somehow compel Apple to put up a false binary...